# Given an array a of n elements, print any value that appears at least three times or print -1 if there is no such value

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, nested-loops

here is my code and it always output -1 and I didn't know why. any help?
Input
The first line contains an integer t (1≤t≤104) — the number of test cases.

The first line of each test case contains an integer n (1≤n≤2⋅105) — the length of the array.

The second line of each test case contains n integers a1,a2,…,an (1≤ai≤n) — the elements of the array.

It is guaranteed that the sum of n over all test cases does not exceed 2⋅105.

Output
For each test case, print any value that appears at least three times or print -1 if there is no such value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n, size,*arr, *frr,count,*ptr,g,s;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&size);
        arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        frr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",arr+j);
                *(frr + j) = -1;
            }
        if(size >= 3)
        {
            for (g = 0; g < size ; g++)
            {
                count=1;
                for(s = g + 1; s < size;s++)
                {
                    if(*(arr + g) == *(arr + s))
                    {
                        count++;
                        *(frr+s) = 0;
                    }             
                }
                if(*(frr+g) != 0 )
                {
                    *(frr+g) = count;
                }

                if(*(frr+g) >= 3)
                {
                    *(ptr+i) = *(arr + g);
                }else
                {
                    *(ptr+i) = -1;
                }
                
            }  
        }else
        {
            *(ptr+i) = -1;
        }
        
        free(arr);
        free(frr);

    }
    for(int j = 0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr+j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag c++ for c questions

Comment: what are you using `frr` for? That bit is quite confusing to me

Comment: Suggestion: you can do each test on its own without the `ptr` array. Simply read the data for each test and print the result each time through the first loop and avoid the 2nd loop altogether.

Comment: I used it to record the frequency of each element of the array

Comment: What is `frr`? in general your code would be much easier to understand (for us and for you) if you used more descriptive variable names

Comment: split into sub functions that you can unit test (`void print_duplicate3(const int* numbers, int count)`).

Comment: Consider what happens to `*(ptr+i)` when you find a repeated element but the next element you check isn't repeated

Comment: Your algorithm cannot work because you only output one number for each test case, but the problem says `print any value that appears at least three times`. So for the array {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2} you should print 1 and 2.

Comment: `*(arr + i)` -> more readable `arr[i]`

Comment: @john I believe this is the expectation. "any" means if there are multiple values print any of them. "all" would mean what you think

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev On reflection I think you are right.

Comment: BTW you don't need to complicate the code by storing the result of each test case, and printing them afterwards. You can print the result as each test is completed.

Comment: Should "2⋅105" be read as "two thousand, one hundred and five"?  That is, is "⋅" being used as a grouping symbol, as opposed to a decimal separator or a multiplication operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `*(ptr+i)` to `-1` for each element of the array. This means that a later element of the array that is not repeated three times will reset  `*(ptr+i)` to `-1`.

Change this

```
            if(*(frr+g) >= 3)
            {
                *(ptr+i) = *(arr + g);
            }
            else
            {
                *(ptr+i) = -1;
            }
```

to this

```
            if(*(ptr+i) == -1 && *(frr+g) >= 3)
            {
                *(ptr+i) = *(arr + g);
            }
```

and at the beginning add this

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
{
    *(ptr + i) = -1;
```

But as has already been said in the comments you do not need either the `ptr` array or the `frr` array. You only run one test at a time so there is no need to keep all the test results before you print any of them out. And you only need to save the frequency of the current element you are testing, so you don't need an array for that either.

And make your code readable, change `*(arr + g)` to `arr[g]`. They both work exactly the same.

Comment: thanks a lot I appreciate your concern

Answer (score 0):

For starters this array allocation

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

does not make a sense. For each given sequence of numbers you can at once output whether the sequence contains three equal elements or not without storing this information in the allocated array.

Also allocating this auxiliary array

```
frr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

makes the code unsafe and inefficient.

It does not make a sense to travers the array if an element that occurs already three times is found.

Otherwise this code snippet

```
            if(*(frr+g) >= 3)
            {
                *(ptr+i) = *(arr + g);
            }else
            {
                *(ptr+i) = -1;
            }
```

for elements that are present in the tail of the array `arr` can incorrectly
set the value `ptr[i]` to `-1` though early there was already found a preceding element that occurs three times.

Without the redundant arrays pointed to by the pointers `ptr` and `frr` the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t t = 0;

    scanf( "%zu", &t );

    while (t--)
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        scanf( "%zu", &n );

        int result = -1;

        if (n)
        {
            int *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                scanf( "%d", a + i );
            }

            for (size_t i = 2; result == -1 && i < n; i++)
            {
                int count = 1;
                for (size_t j = i; count != 3 && j-- != 0; )
                {
                    if (a[j] == a[i]) ++count;
                }

                if (count == 3) result = a[i];
            }

            free( a );
        }

        printf( "%d\n", result );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem altogether differently.  Since the range of the elements is not explicitly bounded, it is a bit tricksome to manage a frequency table.  But the maximum number of elements in each test array is pretty small, so it is feasible to

- declare an array large enough to hold all the elements of any test case
- for each test case,

  - read all the elements into the (one) array
  - sort the array (`qsort()`, or roll your own insertion or selection sort)
  - scan the sorted array to easily detect and report values that appear at least thrice